Problema con radioButton en c#
Tengo un programa de gestor de contenidos multimedia, cuando le pido al usuario que ingrese su contraseña tiene la opción de mostrarla o no, esto lo gestiono con un radioButton. El problema es que cuando pulso el botón la primera vez si que me muestra la contraseña pero cuando lo vuelvo a pulsar para que lo oculte no lo hace. Aquí está mi código:
private void radioButton_MostrarPassword_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(radioButton_MostrarPassword.Checked)
    {
        textBox_ConfirmarPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
        textBox_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
    }

    else
    {
        textBox_ConfirmarPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
        textBox_Password.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
    }

    this.Update();
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No deberias usar un radiobutton, deberias usar un checkbox... tal vez por eso tengas problemas?

Es sumamente obvio, un RadioButton por si no percataste necesita otro radio button en el mismo control padre, el RadioButton sirve para hacer basicamente selecciones multiples ya sabes, o una, o la otra, pero si no tiene otro boton con el siempre se mantendra checkeado, utiliza CheckBox, esa sirve para lo que necesitas.
Puedes cambiar su valor, de seleccionado a no, con la propiedad bool, llamada Checked.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
